# how to call a function by pointer in C

Tags: c

I have been going through the Atmel library USB for AT91SAM7 and there is something I don’t understand. Endpoint is a structure defined as follows:

```
typedef struct {
    volatile unsigned char  state;
    volatile unsigned char  bank;
    volatile unsigned short size;
    Transfer       transfer;        //thus Endpoint contains an instance of "Transfer"  
} Endpoint
```

point;
And Transfer itself is a structure as follows:

```
typedef struct {
    char             *pData;
     volatile int     buffered;
    volatile int     transferred;
    volatile int     remaining;
    volatile  TransferCallback  fCallback;
     void             *pArgument;
} Transfer;
```

And TransferCallback  is a function with the following prototype:

```
typedef  void  (*TransferCallback)(void *pArg,  unsigned char status, unsigned int transferred, unsigned int remaining);
```

also two pointers have been defined as the following:

```
Endpoint *pEndpoint = &(endpoints[bEndpoint]);
Transfer *pTransfer = &(pEndpoint->transfer);
```

I want to know why such a way to call the function TransferCallback  is valid:

```
((TransferCallback) pTransfer->fCallback) (followed by the required arguments passed )
```

But this is not valid:

```
((TransferCallback)pEndpoint->transfer->fCallback)?
```

how could I directly call TransferCallback without using a pointer such as pTransfer  in between?
I tried a number of combinations but none worked.

Comment: Given the code shown, you should be able to write `pEndpoint->transfer->fCallback(...args...)`, with no further adornment, and have it work.  Thus, the problem is with something you have not shown. We need to see a complete self-contained example of code that doesn't work, and ideally also the error messages you're getting, *unedited*.

Answer (score 4):

Note that `Endpoint` does not have a *pointer to Transfer* member (`*Transfer`), but a *Transfer* member. In machine terms, rather than a single word of memory within each `Endpoint` being used as a pointer to a `Transfer`, all the fields of the `Transfer` member are stored *directly* inside the memory allocated for the `Endpoint`.

To cut to the chase, what you need is:

`((TransferCallback)pEndpoint->transfer.fCallback)`

Comment: Alex D. Very quick and subtle.  Really thanks. How come I didn’t notice that?

Comment: and i guess it would have been better in terms of memory usage if "Transfer" had been included in "Endpoint" using a pointer. what's the downside?maybe this way they have saved themselves a lot of explicit casting by directly including "Transfer" inside "Endpoint".

Comment: The 2 are very different in machine terms, and there are a variety of pros/cons either way, but better memory usage is not one of them. Dereferencing a pointer has a small but non-zero cost in CPU cycles, so avoiding an extra dereference is one "pro" to directly storing `Transfer` within `Endpoint`. If you pass an `Endpoint` as an argument to a function, it does mean that a few more words must be pushed on the stack, though. In some cases, you might want multiple `Endpoint` structs to share the *same* `Transfer` -- then your only choice would be to use a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the title to the OP: *how to call a function by pointer in C*

+1 to Alex's answer of your question about *How*, but there is another point that can be made in the interest of knowing *Why* choose a function pointer over just providing the normal function name in the first place;  Function pointers are especially useful in C* (see *)  when you have a collection of functions that are similar in that they contain the same argument list, but have different outputs. You can define an array of function pointers, making it easier, *for example*, to call the functions in that family from a switch, or a loop, or when creating a series of threads in a pool that include similar worker functions as arguments. Calling an array makes it as simple as changing the index of the pointer to get the specific functionality you need for each unique case.

***As a simple example***, the two string functions `strcat()` and `strcpy()` have the argument list: `(char *, const char *)`, therefore, may be assigned to an array of function pointers.  First create the function pointer array:

```
char * (*pStr[2])( char *a, const char *b);` //array of function pointers pStr[]
```

Then, make the assignements of strcat and strcpy to the array:

```
void someFunc(void)
{
    pStr[0] = strcat; //assign strcat to pointer [0]
    pStr[1] = strcpy; //assign strcpy to pointer [1]
}
```

Now, `strcat()` or `strcpy()` can be called as:

```
int main(void)
{
    char a[100]="kjdhlfjgls";
    char b[100]="kjdhlfjgls";

    someFunc();//define function pointers

    pStr[0](a, "aaaaaaaa");  //strcat
    pStr[1](b, "aaaaaaaa");  //strcpy

    return 0;
}
```

***Example output***:
[image]

This is just a simple example.  It does not explore the full extent of usefulness function pointers can provide, but illustrates another reason *why* functions pointers may be preferred in some situations.

*** ***This illustration is targeted only to C***, as opposed to C++, where qualities of inheritance and polymorphism inherent to that language would make this suggestion unnecessary.